# Chamar método de c# no javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Criei um método que chamas os dados de um banco de dados no C#. Como posso chamar esse método no JavaScript ?

Segue código

```
[WebMethod]
    public copa recuperaDados(int cAno)
    {
        var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=(localdb)/MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=C:/USERS/BERNARDO/DOCUMENTS/COPA.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"].ToString();

        copa selecionada = new copa();

        using(SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            string q = "Select * from copa where ano = @ano";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, myCon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ano", cAno);

            using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    selecionada.sede = reader["sede"].ToString();
                    selecionada.campeao = reader["campeao"].ToString();
                    selecionada.vice = reader["vice"].ToString();
                }

                myCon.Close();
            }
            return selecionada;
        }
    }
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#CopaList").change(function () {
    $("#msg").text("A copa de " + $("#CopaList option:selected").text() + " teve como país(es) sede(s) : " + 

        + "O Campeão foi " +  + "O Vice Campeão foi " + 
       )
})
```

Comment: O C# não roda no servidor e o JavaScript no cliente? Não entendi como vc pretende fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo você pode usar ajax pra pegar os dados do backend sem precisar atualizar a página:

```
$("#CopaList").change(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "SuaPagina.aspx/PreencheCampo",
    data: JSON.stringify({ cAno: $("#CopaList option:selected").text() }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: (response) => {
      $("#msg").text("A copa de " + $("#CopaList option:selected").text() + " teve como país(es) sede(s) : " + response.selecionada.sede + ".O Campeão foi " + response.selecionada.campeao + ".O Vice Campeão foi " + response.selecionada.vice);
    },
    error: (response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }
  })
})
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Sua solução parece interessante, mas não está funcionando no meu projeto. Tenho que configurar alguma coisa para o projeto receber suporte de ajax ?

Comment: Qual o erro que está dando amigo?

Comment: A mensagem não é exibida

Answer (score -1):

recuperaDados é o nome da função de backend. Sendo assim, altere o código do @Maycon F. Castro para "SuaPagina.aspx/recuperaDados".

Mas, precisa ver o restante do código. Precisa depurá-lo para ver se está entrando na função recuperaDados.

No navegador, no console (inpecionar elementos) não gera nenhum erro?
Se você chamar direto no navegador pela url "SuaPagina.aspx/recuperaDados?cAno=2020"